# Java recursion in implementing an algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to implement a search algorithm which uses recursion method.

The algorithm should expand `startnode` to its neighbouring nodes and then select the neighbouring node with least cost and then add that cost to the `pathcost`(which is initially 0) and the selected least cost node will become the `startnode` and the search continues again recursively until `goalnode`is found.

Below is my code for implementing this recursion. It isn't giving me any errors but it is not giving me the expected solution.
**INSTEAD** it is adding the cost of each and every neighbouring node (I only need it to add the leastcost node). I have been trying to do it, but can't seem to find any clue how to do it.

```
Queue<String> frontierNodes = new PriorityQueue<String>();
Queue<Node1> frontierCosts = new PriorityQueue<Node1>(); // here Node1 is class storing the start, end and cost of the map.

public void Search(Node1[] nodes, String startnode, String goalnode, int size, double pathcost){

    for(int i=0; i<size;i++) {               
        if(startnode.equalsIgnoreCase(nodes[i].getStartNode())) {              
            frontierNodes.add(nodes[i].getEndNode());  
            frontierCosts.add(new Node1(nodes[i].getCost()));

            System.out.println("Frontier Nodes are " +frontierNodes);
            System.out.println("Path cost till now "+pathcost);
            // Something should be implemented here to add only the least cost
            pathcost += frontierCosts.peek().toCostString();
            System.out.println("Path cost till now "+pathcost);

        }    
    }
    System.out.println("Expanding node... " +frontierNodes.peek());
    //Recursive call
    Search(nodes, frontierNodes.poll(), goalnode, nodes.length-(frontierNodes.size()), pathcost); 

}
```

Comment: actuallly what should happen here is , explore all the neighbours of startNode, compare them, pickup least cost node and add them to your final tally,this is answer to your question
but somehow this doesnt look as an min cost tour algorithm

Comment: Where is the conditional check for comparing cost?  You state you want to select the least cost, but I see no code that compares node costs.

Comment: Actually I am using the priority queue instead of checking the cost, so that I can poll() /peek() the head of the queue (which is the least cost). Doesn't this work? :/

Comment: PriorityQueue may work (I've never used one), but the API says it relies on natural order or a comparator used at creation time.  Unless you have that comparator somewhere else, how do you have the queue order the nodes?

Comment: What prevents you from using [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)?

Comment: Global queue and recursion do not play nicely: if you want a DFS, use recursion or a stack; if you want a BFS (which the word "frontier" suggests) use a queue and a loop, not a recursion. As far as the implementation goes, (a) it does not look like you've got a base case, and (b) it does not look like your code ever backtracks.

Comment: @MadConan Actually I am new to this and I thought priority queue might work. And I didn't quite get your question :/ sorry can you please elaborate it a bit?

Comment: @kaykay I am trying to implement the branch and bound search

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am trying to implement the branch and bound search and I think it doesn't backtrack. Oh yeah I missed the base case, but I am not sure how to write one :/ Something like when the goal node is found, stop the search?

Comment: @Dee Exactly, you need to do something that does not require a recursive call when the target node is found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to use the `PriorityQueue`.  You should be keeping everything within the scope of the recursive method.  For tree traversal recursively, you want to follow the general pattern (psuedo code)

```
int sumOfLeastCost(Node node){
    if(node == null){ return 0; }
    int sum = 0;
    Node min = null;
    for each child{
       if(min == null){
            min = currentChild;
       }else if(currentChild.getCost() < min.getCost()){
            min = currentChild;
            sum = min.getCost();
        }
    }

    return sum + sumOfLeastCost(min);
}
```

This will only follow the branches of minimal cost nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this closer to what you need?

```
public double Search(ArrayList<Node1> nodes, String startnode, String goalnode, double pathcost){

    //Probably needs a better data structure to hold these
    ArrayList<String> neighbours = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> neighbourPathCosts = new ArrayList<>();

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<nodes.size();i++) {               
        if(startnode.equalsIgnoreCase(nodes.get(i).getStartNode())) {              
            neighbours.add(nodes.get(i).getEndNode());  
            neighbourPathCosts.add(nodes.get(i).getCost());
        }
    }

    int indexOfCheapest = -1;
    double cheapest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int j = 0; j < neighbours.size(); j++){
        if(cheapest > neighbourPathCosts.get(i)){
            cheapest = neighbourPathCosts.get(i);
            indexOfCheapest = i;
        }
    }

    pathcost += neighbourPathCosts.get(indexOfCheapest);
    System.out.println("Path cost till now " + pathcost);

    String nextNode = neighbours.get(indexOfCheapest);
    System.out.println("Expanding node... " + nextNode );

    if(startNode.equals(goalNode)){
        return pathcost;
    }else{
        nodes.remove(i);
        //Recursive call
        return Search(nodes, nextNode, goalnode, pathcost); 
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I have tried this and while running it is giving me wrong result with stackoverflow error along with many weird errors :/ (during run time)

Comment: what actually the collections.min is doing here? Is it picking the least cost node?

Comment: Yes Collections.min() gets the smallest, then I use index of to know which one it is.

Comment: Apart from stackoverflow error, there are so many other weird errors. I don't know whats going on.:/

Comment: Something like `at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal$BinaryToASCIIBuffer.dtoa(FloatingDecimal.java:431)`  `at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.appendTo(FloatingDecimal.java:89)`  `at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:709)` etc .....

Comment: They both return double. I have edited my question with Node1 class, please have a look.

Comment: When I am trying to print what is being stored in collections, i.e. the `neighbourPathCosts.add(nodes[i].getCost());`  it is printing as TRUE! and I think this is the reason collections is empty and the code is not working. But I am not sure why getCost() is not adding the cost to the arraylist. `getCost()` method was working fine before but why not in this case? Could you please look into this?

Comment: Does that edit help, if not tell me where the execptions occur and what they are.

Comment: In arguments, I am passing nodes as Node1[] not ArrayList :/ Changing to this changes my whole coding. Can you please do it with Node1[]?

Comment: use Arrays.asList(nodes)

Comment: It is saying as "cannot find symbol" at Double.maxValue()?

Comment: I have tried this and it is not giving me the desired result. It is just displaying as `Index: 8, Size: 2`

Comment: There is some problem in the code at second for loop. The program is not entering that loop. I have even used the enhanced for loop as `for (String neighbour : neighbours) {` Still not working!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77872/discussion-between-george-and-dee).